# Standardizing *any* random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

If $X$ is *any* random variable, and if $Z=\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, then are the following *true* or *false*:

1. The mean of $Z$ is always $0$, regardless of the distribution of $X$.
2. The variance of $Z$ is always $1$, regardless of the distribution of $X$.
3. $Z$ is always normally distributed, regardless of the distribution of $X$.

I ran some quick calculations, and I'am persuaded that the first two statements are true. For statement #3, my intuition says the answer is *false*, but I don't really know how to formulate an answer.

Is this a central limit theorem type question?

Comment: For the first two, just use the definitions of mean and variance for $Z$. For the third, can you find a counter-example?

Comment: To be fussy, it is not *any* random variable, the mean and variance need to exist for the question to make sense, and the variance must be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

For (1):
Subtracting the mean from X will result in E(x-E(x)) = E(x) - E(x) = 0

For (2):
Proof by counter-example (similar to the answer above)

For (3):
Proof by counter-example (as comment above), take X as the Uniform distribution for example.

Multiplying X by 1/(sigma) and subtracting (mu)/(sigma) does not make X normal.

Comment: There is no counterexample to 2 (except for a distribution lacking finite variance).

Comment: Are you claiming that $(2)$ is false? (Assuming, of course, that the mean and variance exist and the variance is not $0$ as noted above).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{Var}}$You first need $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$ to exist (i.e. $E[X^2] < \infty$).

1. Use linearity of expectation to show its true.
2. Use linearity of expectation to show $\var(Z) = E[(Z-0)^2] = E[Z^2] = 1$.
3. Obviously not. Pretty much any non-Gaussian distribution will have this not be Gaussian (e.g. a Bernoulli rv will become $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ times a rademacher).

Answer (score 0):

A simple counterexample suffices for claim #3:  just let $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(0.5)$.  Since $X$ is discrete, $Z = (X - \mu)/\sigma$ is also discrete, which contradicts the claim that $Z$ is normal (hence, continuous).

Of course, even if we restrict the claim to continuous random variables with infinite support, another counterexample is the exponential distribution:  $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$, for $x > 0$.  And if $X$ is required to be continuous with support over the entire real line, then choose the double exponential distribution $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}.$$  The cusp at $f(0)$ cannot be removed by standardization, or indeed, by any nondegenerate location-scale transformation.